# Flask + Jinja and POST/GET variables

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How can I use Jinja2 and Flask to get the hidden variable in this code:

```
<form action="reservation" method="post" name="reservation">

    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reservation</button></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ d[0] }} ">

</form>
```

It would be better may be to use GET but I am stuck with this also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *just another form field*. It may be hidden in your browser, but it is still sent to your Flask server just like any other field.

As such, it'll be found in your `request.form` multidict:

```
id = request.form.get('id')
```